# Why doesn't IntelliJ IDEA allow for correct indentation here?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, indentation, curly-braces

I'm wondering about nested loops/conditionals without braces in Java, due to a possible error I encountered in the Intellij IDEA. As a simple example, what I wish to write is:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    for (int i=0; i<10; i++){
        if (i % 2 == 0){
            System.out.println(i);
        }
    }
    System.out.println("done.");
}
```

Effectively printing all even numbers between 0 and 10, and printing `done.` at the end. No problem.

Let's remove the braces, since they don't seem to be needed.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    for (int i=0; i<10; i++)
        if (i % 2 == 0)
            System.out.println(i);
```

At this point, I press the enter key and expect my indentation to end up aligned with the `for` loop. Here is the potential bug though (or my misunderstanding), since I get aligned with the `if` conditional. What is worse is that IntelliJ IDEA does not even allow me to indent properly: pressing the backspace key gets me back to the previous line.

So, maybe a more concrete question would be:
Is the following code identical to the above code with curly braces?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    for (int i=0; i<10; i++)
        if (i % 2 == 0)
            System.out.println(i);
    System.out.println("done.");
}
```

And if so, why doesn't IntelliJ IDEA allow for the correct indentation?

Comment: "*Let's remove the braces, since they don't seem to be needed.*" FWIW, I'd disagree with that. If someone adds a 2nd println at the same indentation level, it will look very much like both are conditional, when in fact only 1 will be. The other would be unconditional.  The same is true of the for-loop. I would keep the braces there not because they are strictly required but because it will make it less likely a future editor would break it in a difficult to spot way.

Comment: It does _allow_ the indentation you want, use Shift-Tab to dedent rather than trying to delete a level.